# Running Ruby file with an input file in terminal?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I would like to do something like this in terminal

```
$ ruby quicksort.rb unsorted.txt
```

`quicksort.rb` is the ruby file I would like to run `unsorted.txt` is the input file that contains unsorted numbers. Is it possible to do something like this in ruby?

Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me,
`ruby quicksort.rb < unsorted.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the commandline arguments and do a file operation. to read arguments you can use

```
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

This way you can get the filename and get the content.

Answer (score 3):

[`ARGF`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html) makes this kind of task easy, almost as easy as Perl's `<>` operator:

```
$ cat quicksort.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

ARGF.each do |line|
    puts line
end
$ ruby quicksort.rb /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
...
```

You might like to bookmark this [extremely helpful quick guide to Ruby IO](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/fileaccess.html).

Answer (score 2):

For arguments, use argv

```
ARGV.each do|file|
file
end
```

Then you can read contents of the file :

```
f = File.open(file, File::RDONLY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just read from standard in, the shell can do this for you easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts $stdin.read.reverse
```

Then use the "<" to forward the contents of the bar.txt file containing "foobar" to your program.

```
$ ruby foo.rb  < bar.txt 
raboof
```

---

Another solution that more matches what you want to do would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts IO.read(ARGV[0]).reverse
```

running it:

```
$ ruby foo.rb bar.txt 

raboof
```

Answer (score 1):

While I do like solving stuff in Ruby I just want to point out:

```
> sort unsorted.txt > sorted.txt
```

if you have a decent (*nix) command line. But maybe you want to do more than just the sorting?